# Using AutoMapper to map between 2 lists of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, automapper

I use `AutoMapper` to map between my domain model and view model and vice versa.

I normally do my mappings like this in my controller:

```
// Mapping
Tutorial tutorial = (Tutorial)tutorialMapper.Map(viewModel, typeof(TutorialEditViewModel), typeof(Tutorial));
```

My tutorial mapper class to handle the above:

```
public class TutorialMapper : ITutorialMapper
{
     static TutorialMapper()
     {
          Mapper.CreateMap<TutorialCreateViewModel, Tutorial>();
          Mapper.CreateMap<TutorialEditViewModel, Tutorial>();
          Mapper.CreateMap<Tutorial, TutorialEditViewModel>();
     }

     public object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
     {
          return Mapper.Map(source, sourceType, destinationType);
     }
}
```

I'm trying to shorten my way of mapping between lists.  I currently do it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Tutorial> tutorialsList = tutorialService.GetAll();
IEnumerable<TutorialListViewModel> tutorialListViewModels =
     from t in tutorialsList
     orderby t.Name
     select new TutorialListViewModel
     {
          Id = t.Id,
          Name = t.Name,
          IsActive = t.IsActive
     };
```

Is it possible to map it soemthing like this?

I know that AutoMapper supports mapping of lists, but how would I implement it into my scenario?

I also tried the following:

```
IEnumerable<Tutorial> tutorialsList = tutorialService.GetAll();
IEnumerable<TutorialListViewModel> tutorialListViewModels = (IEnumerable<TutorialListViewModel>)tutorialMapper.Map(tutorialsList, typeof(IEnumerable<Tutorial>), typeof(IEnumerable<TutorialListViewModel>));
```

But if there are no items in tutorialsList then I get the following error:

```
{"The entity type Tutorial is not part of the model for the current context."}
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I never defined my Tutorial entity set in my context file.  It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        IList<City> cities = db.Cities.ToList();

        IList<CityViewModel> viewModelList = Mapper.Map<IList<City>, IList<CityViewModel>>(cities);
        return View(viewModelList);
    }
```